# MongoDB aggregate doesn't return objects which have the same values

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express

I use aggregate functionality to get back array with specific criteria. So aggregate run through all documents in collection, then through all pets arrays in documents and finally through all treatments arrays which are nested in pets arrays.

```
  db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$pets"},{$group:{"_id":"$pets.treatments"}},
        {$unwind:"$_id"},{$group:{"_id":"$_id"}},{$match:
{"_id.name":"name"}}
```

As Result i get sth like this:

```
[{"_id": 
{"name":"vet","treatment":"misoshiur","paid":"NO","opinion":"Good"}}, 
{"_id":{"name":"vet","treatment":"czekolada","paid":"NO","opinion":""}},
{"_id":
{"name":"vet","treatment":"misoshiur","paid":"NO","opinion":"Excellent"}},etc...]
```

My Problem is that it can happen that i will have exactly the same two objects or more.

```
{"_id":
{"name":"vet","treatment":"misoshiur","paid":"NO","opinion":"Excellent"}}
    {"_id":
{"name":"vet","treatment":"misoshiur","paid":"NO","opinion":"Excellent"}}
```

Then when i carry on my command in mongodb and i have two, exactly the same objects, it doesn't return them, it just return one, why is that? And how to make it return all objects? Even these objects that are exactly the same?

Actually i am not so experience with mognodb, even if the query is not so perfect, it gives me what i asked for ;) But could somebody please explain me why mongodb after using $match, reject objects which it already have in array? I my project it is important because i am counting opinions and it could be that opinion will be duplicated by somebody.

JSON

```
 [{
"_id" : ObjectId("550361c38323c1f65dae65c3"),
"username" : "pet",
"password" : "pet",
"character" : "pet",
"pets" : [
    {
        "name" : "cat",
        "kind" : "micoc",
        "age" : "2",
        "treatments" : [
            {
                "name" : "vet",
                "treatment" : "czekolada",
                "paid" : "NO",
                "opinion" : "Good"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "io",
        "kind" : "dog",
        "age" : "5",
        "treatments" : [
            {
                "name" : "vet",
                "treatment" : "misoshiur",
                "paid" : "NO",
                "opinion" : "Excellent"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}]
```

My aim is to create array which will have all objects from all documents nested treatments array. So each document has pets array and each object in pets array has treatments array. I want to take all these treatments arrays in all documents and the using $match specify name. So as result i have array which contain objects from all treatments arrays in all documents, which name key is equal to some user.

Comment: Completely unclear as to what you are trying to do. `{ "$uwnind": "$_id" },{ "{ "$group": { "_id": "$_id" }}` is doing nothing here.

Comment: I am not so experience with mognodb but i did this in order to  get one array with objects as result. If you don't mind i would be very happy if you would correct me. I updated question.

Comment: Could you perhaps show some documents and the results you want to achieve from them.

Comment: So now we have a document but what is the result you want from that data? How about from multiple documents? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I am not sure what did you mean by "using $match specify name" because pets array also has "name" and treatments array also has "name". I have assumed you want to $match on "pets.name" and get all the treatments in an array. 
Since, pets is an array first unwind them then do unwind on treatments as it is also an array then match with 'pets.name' then do group by 'pets.name' and push to treatments array.

```
   aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$pets"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "pets.name": "io"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$pets.treatments"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$pets.name",
            treatments: {
                $push: "$pets.treatments"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The output will be something like this.

```
{
    "_id": "io",
    "treatments": [
        {
            "name": "vet",
            "treatment": "misoshiur",
            "paid": "NO",
            "opinion": "Excellent"
        }
    ]
}
```

If You want to $match on pets.treatment.name then replace $match with "$pets.treatments.name" and _id in $group with "$pets.treatments.name". `Writing $match before unwinding pets.treatment and $group will optimize the query.`